# Can a java .war file contain a webserver

Tags: java, servlets, jenkins

I'm looking into installing Jenkins, in the instructions it says

> "Easy installation: Just java -jar jenkins.war, or deploy it in a
>   servlet container. No additional install, no database."

I understand the servlet container method, but does the above statement mean that just installing Java and running the .war file will somehow spinup a webserver and start serving  http request ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the war file contains the built-in [Winstone](http://winstone.sourceforge.net/) servlet container, and running that command will start it and make it listen for requests on port 8080.

**Edit**: Jenkins 1.535 and above bundles Jetty (rather than Winstone). You can still run it with `java -jar jenkins.war`.

Comment: Jenkins 1.535 and above bundles Jetty (rather than Winstone) so you can just run java -jar jenkins.war.  See https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jetty

Comment: @Brice Thanks for the update, I've edited my answer with that info.

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins comes bundled with [Winstone](http://winstone.sourceforge.net/), a very lightweight servlet container.  As such, Jenkins can be started from the command line as stated by the instructions without any additional software installation.